# how to include the command/filter awk into command watch?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

my command run fine:

`free -h -w | awk '{print $7}'`

but how I can run using `watch`:

`watch -n.6 "free -h -w | awk '{print $7}'";` ???

(that retun error)

PD:

yes, I want only column `available` from `free`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the error you get.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the problem if you try what you posted. Look at the `watch` output. I see something like this:

`Every 2.0s: free -h -w | awk '{print }'`

The $7 is being resolved to nothing before watch gets to it.
You need to escape the $7 somehow.

This seems to work for me:

`watch "free -h -w | awk '{print \$7}'"`

Comment: The actual answer is your first sentence "You can see the problem if you try what you posted. Look at the watch output.", the trick is 1) perform the command in double quotes 2) watch the command output at the top of the watch output, then add escape '\' in front of anything chars that are missing.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting `\` in front of `$7`? i.e.,

`watch -n.6 "free -h -w | awk '{print \$7}'";`

The code without `\` does not work because `$7` is expanded in the double quotes. The shell tries to replace `$7` (a [positional parameter](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters)) with its content, which is likely to be blank. So in effect, you are running something like `... awk '{print }'`.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you receiving?

You are almost there, you just need a backslash in front of the $7

watch -n.6 "free -h -w | awk '{print \$7}'";

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `$` by using a backslash: `\`

```sh
watch -n.6 "free -h -w | awk '{print \$7}'";
```

---

That said, you still won't get the desired output, since not all the values are on the 7'th column. Consider a `/proc/meminfo` alternative;

```
awk '/MemFree/ { printf "%.3f \n", $2/1024/1024 }' /proc/meminfo
```

Using watch:

```
watch "awk '/MemFree/ { printf \"%.3f \n\", \$2/1024/1024 }' /proc/meminfo"
```

Comment: many thanks @Paul Rubel and others sysAdmins, yeah!, use ``\`` resolve problem. :-)
how yours discovery that error ? some LOG ? or "logic/experience" ? Now my command is full: ``watch -n.6 "date +%s%N;free -h -w | awk '{print \$7}'";``

Comment: sorry master @0stone0 I run your command in my CentOs 7 and this no't return info: ``watch "awk '/MemFree/ { printf \"%.3f \n\", \$2/1024/1024 }' /proc/meminfo"``

Comment: Are you sure? I'm testing this on CentOs8 and it's working as expected.